# how to make number running from 60 to 0 and print on textview in android studio

Tags: java, android, printing, numbers, countdown

```
       Runnable r = new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
            try{
                    For (int i = 60; i >= 1; i--) {        
                    System.out.print(i + "\r");
                    // Let the thread sleep for a while.
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    TextView box2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box2);
                    box2.setText("\r" + i + " sec left");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
```

How to make number running from 60 to 0 and print on text view in android    studio and what is the correct way to print in text view in android studio.thank you for your help!

Comment: Use a handler.postDelayed(); method with a runnable.

Comment: thank you so much for your help bro !

Comment: I have also added an answer to explain a little bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Initialize your TextView in onCreate() first:**

```
TextView box2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box2);
```

**Then you can use a handler with postDelayed() method to create a countdown timer:**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 60; i >= 1; i--) {
            box2.setText("\r" + i + " sec left");
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: it works! thank you so much.but why android studio can't read carriage return (\r) ?

Comment: \r doesn't mean anything. I only know \n which means a new line.

Comment: I always use \r in eclipse for print sequences of number in "one line only",but it can't be read by android studio.

Comment: Well, it will still be written in one line as long as you don't write \n. So no need to write \r.